# Concurrent Blocking Flag in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

I sometimes write code like:

Method 1:

```java
synchronized (someMonitor) {
    newInfo = true;
    someMonitor.notifyAll();
}
```

Method 2:

```java
synchronized (someMonitor) {
    while (!newInfo) {
        someMonitor.wait();
    }
    newInfo = false;
}
```

I imagine there's a higher-level concurrency object in the API to handle this. It should work like:

Method 1:

```java
ensureFlagRaised();
```

Method 2:

```java
blockUntilFlagRaisedThenLowerFlag();
```

I could use a BlockingQueue with capacity 1 to call the non-blocking offer(dummyElement) and the blocking take().  But this seems like an abuse of that class.

Any cleaner solutions?

Comment: You can use a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)

Comment: Or use [AbstractQueuedSynchronizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html). A bunch of things in java.util.concurrent are built using this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this.

The most direct replacement would be to switch using `Lock` and `Signal`, which mimics closely the `synchronized/wait/notify` mechanism.

But for a simple flag, the easiest approach is probably a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). With it, your example code could look like the following:

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0, true); // No permits to start with, acquire will block

// Producer loop
makeNewDataAvailable();
s.release();  // Raise "flag" to indicate new info
possiblyDoSomethingUseful();
s.acquire();  // A fair semaphore, so waiting threads get the permit

// Consumer loop
s.acquire();  // Blocks until "flag" raised, then acquires it
processNewData();
s.release();  // Pass the permit back to thread 1
```

But `Semaphore` does require you to plan your logic correctly, otherwise you could end up in a deadlock.

A producer/consumer situation is solved better with other mechanisms though, as you see the code can look confusing and you need to keep track of who's calling `acquire/release` and when. The above code could be better implemented with for example [Exchanger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html):

```
Exchanger<String> e = new Exchanger<>();

// Producer loop
e.exhange(generateNewData());  // Ignore consumer's response

// Consumer loop
processData(e.exchange(null)); // Get data, send dummy back
```

Comment: This Semaphore solution works.  Since the producer might loop multiple times for a single loop of the consumer, I would modify this to have the producer only call release() and then have the consumer call acquire(availablePermits()).  It still seems like abusing the API, but your proposal is better than the solutions I thought of.

Comment: @JoshB it's not abusing at all, Semaphore is very versatile for different uses. Just use `drainPermits()` instead of `acquire(availablePermits())`. Although I don't see why you wouldn't just use a `BlockingQueue`, it seems like a basic producer/consumer situation that you have.